# Publishing Check-in via Facebook IOS SDK

Tags: ios4, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to publish a check-in on a users wall. I don't need to get the longitude and latitude of the users device. But rather have this static as well as the place the user will check-in too. Basically a "check-in" button that already has static coordinates and a message.

I got the demo app up and running but can't seem to find any step by step tutorials on this particular topic. Is there any link around or a sample project you can point me to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to have a place id. Assuming you have that you can use the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing) to make a feed post to check-in the user.

You can do something like this  (using [Facebook iOS SDK 3.0](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/)):

```
[FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:@"Awesome place!"
                                        place:@"110506962309835"
                                         tags:nil
                            completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                id result,
                                                NSError *error) {
        //verify result
                            }
     ];
```

Or:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                             parameters:@{@"place":@"110506962309835"}
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        //verify result
    }];
```

You will need to ask the user for publish_stream permission before making this call.